# iajc and aspectpath

Tags: ant, aspectj

I'm a bit confused with the aspectpath option of the iajc compiler.

My project use AspectJ to weave metric code into an existing swing application.

All the application source are packaged this way:

```
com.xxx.yyy.myapp.*
```

We have put our aspect in a package inside the same project:

```
com.xxx.yyy.aop.*
```

The project is built with javac first and the outpout goes into `${classes.dir}`.

Then we invoke iacj this way:

```
<iajc inpath="${classes.dir}" 
                                destDir="${classes.dir}" 
                                fork="true" 
                                maxmem="${aspectj.maxmem}" 
                                verbose="true" 
                                showWeaveInfo="true" 
                                debug="true"
                                source="1.6"
                                target="1.6">

                                <classpath refid="ajclasspath"/>
                    </iajc>
```

and

```
<path id="ajclasspath">
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <pathelement location="${scm.home}/ant_libs/aspectjrt.jar"/>
            </path>
```

With that said, do i need to specify an aspectpath in the iajc?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html) similar to classpath, aspectpath contains read-only, binary aspect libraries that are woven into sources but not included in the output. In your case you include your aspects in output and they are in `${classes.dir}` with normal classes.
So you don't have to specify `aspectpath` when you don't want to separate your aspects.